# How to get positions in Elasticsearch from partial search query keywords?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Are there any ways to fulfill this scenario below?

Example text: "I want to eat"

I will try to match "ant to" which matches partially with the phrase "want to".

What I want is like below:

My ideal search result would be (tokenized space positions)

- startToken = 1 ("want" is in index token 1)
- startChar = 1 ("a" is in index char 1 with index token is 1)
- endToken = 2
- endChar = 1

but it seems to not be native in Elasticsearch, can Elasticsearch give me the result at least like this? (text positions full, zero-based index position)

- startChar = 3
- endChar = 8

After I searched the Internet I got some clue to use highlighting but after I tried, it failed for partial searching.

Can you give me some best practices for this scenario in Elasticsearch?

Comment: Since you're only matching by exact substring maybe it's easier to compute substring position in your application?

Comment: @ilvar but it will take too much resource on the backend and maybe when we implemented it, the search algorithm does not have the best practice.

Comment: Don't reinvent the algorithm, just use one from the standard library.